How do I change current date highlighted color in Calendar Kit in iOS swift?
I want to change the highlighted color of today from red to any other color, how can I do it in CalendarKit?
Check sample image
I have tried to achieve it with DayViewStyle() method but it through an error & not found in CalendarKit/DayViewController type class.
func createCustomDayViewStyle() -> DayViewStyle {
        var style = DayViewStyle()
        
        // Customize the style for the current date
        style.currentDate.backgroundColor = .blue // Change to your desired color
        style.currentDate.textColor = .white // Change to your desired text color
        
        return style
    }


Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit?
